# Changes to xml file not being recognized - ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, xml, configuration, configuration-files

I read a xml file (`myConfig.config`) and provide it as an input to a CLR method. When I make changes to this xml file, it doesn't seem to be recognizing it. When this line throws an error, I always see the first version of the file as a part of the error message.

In the config file properties, I have set `Copy to Output Directory` as `Copy always`, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by doing a "Copy if newer" option

Answer (score 0):

Copy Always works for windows where the BIN file contains the exe; you don't need that for web sites necessarily...  What does your code look like?  Where does the save occur?